# How to prove $n = \sqrt{1+(n-1)\sqrt{1+n\sqrt{1+(n+1)\sqrt{...}}}}$

Tags: convergence-divergence, induction

This problem is brought in [Introduction to Algorithms: A Creative Approach](https://books.google.com/books/about/Introduction_to_Algorithms.html?id=mJ4ZAQAAIAAJ)  to show common errors in mathematical induction.

**Problem:** For all natural values of $n$, prove that:

$$n=\sqrt{1+(n-1)\sqrt{1+n\sqrt{1+(n+1)\sqrt{...}}}}\quad\mathcal{\color{navy}{(I)}}$$

**Wrong Solution:**
for $n=1$  we have $1 = \sqrt{1+ 0(...)}$ which is true.
By induction hypothesis:
$$n=\sqrt{1+(n-1)\sqrt{1+n\sqrt{1+(n+1)\sqrt{1+(n+2)\sqrt{...}}}}} $$
$$n^2=1+(n-1)\sqrt{1+n\sqrt{1+(n+1)\sqrt{1+(n+2)\sqrt{...}}}} $$
$$n^2-1=(n-1)\sqrt{1+n\sqrt{1+(n+1)\sqrt{1+(n+2)\sqrt{...}}}} $$
$$\implies \frac{(n-1)(n+1)}{(n-1)}=\sqrt{1+n\sqrt{1+(n+1)\sqrt{1+(n+2)\sqrt{...}}}}\qquad \mathcal{\color{navy}{(II)}}$$
$$\implies n+1=\sqrt{1+n\sqrt{1+(n+1)\sqrt{1+(n+2)\sqrt{...}}}}$$
$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

There are two errors in the wrong solution:

- We have to prove that the expression $\mathcal{\color{navy}{(I)}}$ converges for all $n$, so that the claim is meaningful and $1 = \sqrt{1+ 0(...)}$ holds.
- In $\mathcal{\color{navy}{(II)}}$ we have to check we did not devide by zero. Actually the induction step fails from $n = 1$ to $n = 2$. I'm not sure changing the base case (e.g. $2=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3\sqrt{...}}}}$) helps!

Please help me resolve the errors.

Answer (score 2):

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence given by the recurrence relation below :
$$\begin{cases}a_0=0\\
a_1=1\\
a_2=?\\
a_n^2=1+(n-1)a_{n+1}& \text{if $n>1$}
\end{cases}$$
We calculate $a_2$. Assuming the sequence as a differentiable function $f$, we have
$$f(x)^2=1+(x-1)f(x+1)\text{, then}\\
2f(x)f'(x)=f(x+1)+(x-1)f'(x+1)$$
Therefore, $$2f(0)f'(0)=f(1)+(0-1)f'(1)\implies f'(1)=1\\
2f(1)f'(1)=f(2)+(1-1)f'(2)\implies f(2)=2$$
We have $a_2=2$. Now mathematical induction can be used. Assuming that $a_n=n$, which is true for $n=0,1,2$, we have then
$$n^2=1+(n-1)a_{n+1}\implies a_{n+1}=\frac{n^2-1}{n-1}=n+1$$

Comment: Good job! I expected a much more complicated answer.

Comment: Where do you prove that the sequence $$\sqrt{1+1\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3\sqrt{\cdots\cdots+(n-1)\sqrt{1+n}}}}}$$ converges?

Comment: @Did In fact, l'Hôpital's rule is used when we calculate $a_2$. The problem is, if we give different $a_2$, for example $a_2=3$, the recurrence relation can also be well-defined. Therefore, if there is no $a_2$ given by the formula, it makes nonsense. What I did is just to find a reasonable value of $a_2$ so that the recurrence relation is well-defined.

Comment: But one cannot chose values at will, can one? The task is to prove that if $$a_{n,n}=1\qquad a_{k-1,n}=\sqrt{1+ka_{k,n}}$$ for every $1\leqslant k\leqslant n$, then $(a_{0,n})$ converges (and that its limit is $2$).

Comment: @Did I think that in your formula, we can never know the value of $a_{n,n}$ for each $n$. Why should we have the same valve when $n$ changes? However, if $a_{n,n}$ is constant (not even equal to $1$), your sequence is surely convergent to $2$, and it seems not easy to prove that....

Comment: @Aforest You noted that the formula in my first comment is an option to give a rigorous meaning to the question asked (which has none unless one explains the meaning of the ending "$\cdots$" in the post's formula). If your point is that other options are possible, I concur but I am somewhat surprised then that your own answer does no even touch upon the problem... Re the convergence to $2$, yes, if true, **this needs a proof** (my same point again).

Comment: @Did I mean, depending on the option we choose, the sequence may not even be convergent when we calculate $a_2$, thus I supposed the post's formula is not well-defined (I think that's why the book brought this question). In my answer, I just explained why we give $a_2=2$ to make this question be well-defined. If you successfully prove that your sequence is convergent to $2$, I don't think it will explain more things than me, because there are many other options. I just chose a easy way to complete the recurrence relation.